# How do I create a feature vector if I don’t have all the data?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

So say for each of my ‘things’ to classify I have:
{house, flat, bungalow, electricityHeated, gasHeated, ... }

Which would be made into a feature vector:
{1,0,0,1,0,...} which would mean a house that is heated by electricity.

For my training data I would have all this data- but for the actual thing I want to classify I might only have what kind of house it is, and a couple other things- not all the data ie.
{1,0,0,?,?,...}

So how would I represent this?

I would want to find the probability that a new item would be gasHeated.

I would be using a SVM linear classifier- I don’t have any core to show because this is purely theoretical at the moment. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

When I read this question, it seems that you may have confused with feature and label.

You said that you want to predict whether a new item is "gasHeated", then "gasHeated" should be a label rather than a feature.

btw, one of the most-common ways to deal with missing value is to set it as "zero" (or some unused value, say -1). But normally, you should have missing value in both training data and testing data to make this trick be effective. If this only happened in your testing data but not in your training data, it means that your training data and testing data are not from the same distribution, which basically violated the basic assumption of machine learning.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a trained model and a testing sample {?,0,0,0}. Then you can create two new testing samples, {1,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0}, and you will have two predictions.

I personally don't think SVM is a good approach if you have missing values in your testing dataset. Just like I have mentioned above, although you can get two new predictions, but what if each one has different predictions? It is difficult to assign a probability to results of SVM in my opinion unless you use logistic regression or Naive Bayes. I would prefer Random Forest in this situation.